# Finding the interface/route for a local IP address on Mac OS X and iOS?

Tags: ios, objective-c, macos, networking

I'm working on a machine that has multiple local network interfaces. Each interface is on a distinct network: for example, `en0` might be `10.0.0.x`, `en1` `192.168.1.x`, etc.

I'd like to programatically answer the question: "Which interface is likely to be able to get to the given local IP address?"

For instance, if I wanted to talk to `10.0.0.75`, that would be `en0`, `192.168.1.4` would be `en1`. I'm sure there's a smarter way to do this than manually comparing IP address fragments.

Bonus points if this works on iOS as well as Mac OS X - iOS does support multiple local interfaces, even if it's rare.

Comment: There’s a good reason this is hard: this is a low level concern. If you’re trying to make a network connection you should just let the (battle tested) network libraries handle this. Can you explain more about *why* you would like to do this? (What problem are you trying to solve?)

Answer (score 1):

The approach I'd consider is to enumerate all the configured interfaces and get their IP-address and netmask. You can then calculate the Hostmin and Hostmax for that subnet, if your candidate falls within the Hostmax-Hostmin IP-range this host should be reachable directly on the local subnet of that interface.

You can find an online tool for these types of calculations at http://jodies.de/ipcalc. It's fairly straightforward bit-operations to do these calculations programatically.

There are IP-address functions you can use in `arpa/inet.h`, `inet_addr` for instance will give you a 32-bit value from a dotted-decimals formatted IP-address.